# In MySQL, how a kill a long running query by Slave Thread?

Tags: kill, slave, long-running-processes, mysql-5.7, processlist

In MySQL, we can kill a running query by simple "**kill**" command with process id of the command:

For example:

```
kill 29871 ;
```

But how to kill a long running query running by slave thread having the user **system_user** ?

I have its process id from show processlist but when i kill that id it again starts running that query. Also I am unable to stop the slave by using **STOP SLAVE** because it waits for the query to complete.

Is there any possible solution to kill the long running query by slave thread without restart ?